# Do I need to use Kinesis Data Streams (if I use Firehose) to stream data to parquet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Consider the architecture below (source [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-apache-parquet-optimized-data-using-amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-amazon-athena-and-amazon-redshift/)):
Why do we need **Kinesis Data Streams**? If the data goes through **Kinesis Data Firehose**, do I **need** to **worry** about Kinesis Data Stream shards, their scaling, etc?

**Goal**: I'm hoping to dump data to S3 in **parquet** with their **Glue** catalog, from a set of producers (e.g. CDC streams and API calls). I was hoping for Kinesis (Firehose) to handle autoscaling, etc, but my understanding is that if Kinesis Data Streams, that wouldn't be the case.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that Kinesis Data Streams is required because Amazon Connect does not have the ability to send directly to Kinesis Data Firehose. Feel free to ask via a comment on the blog post.

Comment: yeah to consume amazon connect data kinesis data streams is required, and kinesis data streams can then serve as  producer of kinesis data firehose, I'm open for discussion feel free to ask via comments section

Comment: Thanks. @varnit That's interesting, but e.g. does Kinesis Firehose support data ingestion from lambdas? If so, wouldn't one be able (in principle) to ingest anything through them into Firehose?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina, you are right, Kinesis Data Firehose supports lambda as a source, and if you don't need real-time processing (in that case firehose captures and loads data in near real-time) there is no reason to add kinesis stream to the pipeline rather use firehose directly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-name.html